# I am not able to export useHistory in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I have imported useHistory as follows.
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

used it properly
const history = useHistory();

But when I am trying this on my react component. I am getting an error, can someone help me in this.
<StyledHeader onClick={()=>history.push("/")}>Crypto Tracker

This is the error message
export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)

Also I have latest react-router-dom in package.json
"react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",

Does someone have solution of this problem

Comment: React router v6 does not have a useHistory. See marked duplicate

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332007/21957513